# R6 documentation using ROxygen

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is any accurate resource for R6 class documentation using ROxygen. I have found several old references online but these don't seem to be accurate anymore.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `roxygen2` version 7 supports R6 documentation, but there's not a lot of ressources. You can see some examples in my package [PlaneGeometry](https://github.com/stla/PlaneGeometry).

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I was missing the @title on the top of the class and it was messing things up.